# Magento: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalogrule_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento, backend

I just made a few changes to my webshop by admininterface (no big one, like no short media URL..) and now every time I log in to Magento it shows up the following Error. I can't see anything else. The frontend is still working.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalogrule_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 546

What could be the matter and how can I fix it? Would be great if somebody could help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've edited some core files.

Be sure that this file exists: `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Helper/Data.php`

That it defines this class: `Mage_CatalogRule_Helper_Data`

And that the class declared in global/helpers in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml` as:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_CatalogRule>
            <version>1.6.0.1</version>
        </Mage_CatalogRule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <catalogrule>
                <class>Mage_CatalogRule_Helper</class>
            </catalogrule>
        </helpers>
....
```

And refresh your configuration cache.

Also check that you're not overrideing the `catalogrule` helper node in any of the local/community code pools.

Comment: If it's a cache problem, rember to delete the cache files in the "var" ordner ...