# Magento site gives function load() on a non-object fatal error

Tags: magento-1.7

I have download code magento site from server and setup in localhost but it give me these two different errors-

> Frontend- Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /var/www/chic54/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225

And

> Admin panel- Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalogrule_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/chic54/app/Mage.php on line 546

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711295/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-catalogrule-helper-data-not-found

Comment: I overwrite my code and now site is working fine.